# Wearable.DataApi.getDataItems Buffer is empty

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

**EDIT:**

Of course I missed something embarrassingly obvious... The GoogleApiClient was not connected.

---

I'm trying to synchronise some data between my phone and a watch. I decided to use the `Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem` method for that but when I try to retrieve the data on the wearable the `itemBuffer` is empty... I must be doing something wrong and can't figure out what it is.

**Provide the data:**

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
oos.writeObject(article);
PutDataRequest request = PutDataRequest
        .createWithAutoAppendedId(WearApiConstants.NEWS_BREAKING)
        .setData(bos.toByteArray());
Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(mGoogleApiClient, request).await();
```

**Retrieve the data:**

```
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
builder.scheme(PutDataRequest.WEAR_URI_SCHEME)
       .path(WearApiConstants.NEWS_BREAKING);
Uri uri = builder.build();

DataItemBuffer itemBuffer = 
       Wearable.DataApi.getDataItems(mGoogleApiClient, uri, DataApi.FILTER_PREFIX)
                       .await();
```

Did I miss anything obvious? If not, can you suggest an approach to debug this problem?